# Is there relationship between tensor as an operator and its contraction?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

According to [Wikipedia article on Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_(intrinsic_definition)#Definition:_Tensor_Product_of_Vector_Spaces).

> The space of type (1, 1) tensors $V \otimes V^*$ is isomorphic in a natural way to the space of linear transformations from V to V.

Is there relation between such and the contraction of $V \otimes V^*$?

Comment: one thing is tensor's rank (or type) and another the contraction operation among tensors

Answer (score 1):

Given an element $v\otimes f$ of $V\otimes V^*$ you can construct:

1) Its **contraction** $f(v)$, which produce a scalar, in $\mathbb R$, if $V$ is a vector space over this field, since $f:V\to\mathbb R$ is linear functional (by the definition of $V^*$).

2) A **linear transformation** $V\to V$ through $w\mapsto f(w)v$. This assignment, $V\otimes V^*\to\hom(V,V)$, is an isomorphism between vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is the second linear transformation $g(w):V \rightarrow V$ in fact $g=(w*v^*)*v=a*v$ where a is a real number? And in that case is it correct to say such linear transformations always scale the vector by just a real number?

Comment: are you referring to $f(w)v$? there, we are scaling $v$ with the number $f(w)$, which coincide with $a*v$ that you are writing.

Comment: you can see a matrix of the transformation associated to $f$ and a basis $\{b_k\}$ of $V$, by evaluating $f(b_i)b_j$.

Comment: I'm not a math major, so excuse me if what I'm asking is naive. I thought the tensor products represent compositions or some amalgam of it's vectors, for example a transformation matrix is a function made out of it's two vectors, but in your example the argument, w, is sandwiched between V and it's dual, can you please make it clear for me?

Comment: ok, I will clarify in a while, meanwhile I suggest you to complete the details for the isomorphism, tell me: could You?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get what you mean by the details of the isomorphism!

Comment: let us call $Lw=f(w)v$: to deeply understand the result one has to demonstrate that this map $L$ is a) is a linear transformation $V\to V$, b)  that $L$ is injective and c) $L$ is surjective. These tasks justify that $L$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I read the Wikipedia article on outer product and figured it out. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linear map $m:V\to V$ and you use this isomorphism to treat it as an element of $V\otimes V^*$ then you can apply contraction to get an element of the underlying field. This is precisely the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29) of $m$, $\mathrm{tr}(m)$.